# Error when creating python module

Tags: python, c, distutils

I have a C code which calls a Fortran subroutine called SetFlags.  I would like to turn this C code into a python module. It creates a .so file, but I cannot import this module into python. I am not sure if my error is in the creation of the module using distutils or in linking to the fortran library.
Here is my setflagsmodule.c file

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
#include "/Users/person/program/x86_64-Darwin/include/Cheader.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char module_docstring[] = 
    "This module provides an interface for Setting Flags in C";

static char setflags_docstring[] = 
    "Set the Flags for program";



static PyObject * setflags(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int *error;
    const int mssmpart;
    const int fieldren;
    const int tanbren;
    const int higgsmix;
    const int p2approx;
    const int looplevel;
    const int runningMT;
    const int botResum;
    const int tlcplxApprox;


    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iiiiiiiiii", &error,&mssmpart,&fieldren,&tanbren,&higgsmix,&p2approx,&looplevel,&runningMT,&botResum,&tlcplxApprox))
        return NULL;

    FSetFlags(error,mssmpart,fieldren,tanbren,higgsmix,p2approx,looplevel,runningMT,botResum,tlcplxApprox); //Call fortran subroutine
    return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef setflags_method[] = {
    {"FSetFlags", setflags, METH_VARARGS, setflags_docstring},
    {NULL,NULL,0,NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC init_setflags(void)
{
    PyObject *m;
    m = Py_InitModule3("setflags", setflags_method, module_docstring);
        if (m == NULL)
            return;
}
```

Here is my setup file called setflags.py:

```
    from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
    ext_modules=[Extension("setflags",["setflagsmodule.c"], include_dirs=['/Users/person/program/x86_64-Darwin'],
    library_dirs=['/Users/person/program/x86_64-Darwin/lib/'], libraries=['FH'])],
    )
```

I build the module using:

```
python setflags.py build_ext --inplace
```

When I try to import the module into python this is the result:

```
>>> import setflags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initsetflags)
```

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to solve this ImportError?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you tried just removing all the Fortran references and seeing if you get the same error? That would be the obvious way to rule out your question.

Comment: Why are bothering with distutils packaging when you don't even have the module running yet? Get it working first, then worry about packaging.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: A lot of people don't know how to compile C extensions without distutils, because that's the first (and, for POSIX, only) way the tutorial shows you how to do it. See [Compilation and Linkage](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#compilation-and-linkage). And even after you learn how to do `cc $(python-config --cflags) $(python-config --ldflags) foomodule.c -o foomodule.so`, it's often easier to write the `setup.py` once and be done with it.

Comment: Interesting. I could never figure out how to get distutils to work for my library. But then, I'm a C programmer first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is very simple, but easy to miss.

Notice the error you get:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initsetflags)
```

Now look at your code:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC init_setflags(void)
```

You've defined `init_setflags` instead of `initsetflags`. Just remove the extra underscore, and it should work.

---

From the documentation on [The Module's Method Table and Initialization Function](http://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function):

> The initialization function must be named `initname()`, where `name` is the name of the module…

---

The reason you often see `init` functions named `init_foo` in examples is that they're usually initializing a module `_foo.so`, which will then be wrapped by a pure-Python module `foo.py`.